# Relation between two stochastics

Tags: stochastic-calculus, probabilistic-method

I got stuck trying to figuring out how to show the following question in probabilistic theory:

"We say that A and B (with P(A), P(B) > 0) attract each other when 
P(A|B) > P(A)."
I've shown that when A attracts B, B also attracts A.

But now I have problems showing that when B is attracted to A with P(NOT B) > 0, NOT B is not attracted to A. ( P(NOT B | A) > P(NOT B) should not be true )

I've tried to make use of the formula P(NOT B | A) = 1 - P(B|A) but there was no real success. Maybe someone has an idea about the technique of proof? 
My idea was to assume that P(NOT B | A) > P(NOT B) is true and then show that its not true because of something.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You assume : $P(B|A)>P(B)$

so: $-P(B|A)<-P(B)$

so: $1-P(B|A)<1-P(B)$

The complement rule for conditional probabilities tells us : $1-P(B|A)=P(NOT B|A)$

so: $P(NOT B|A)<P(NOTB)$

so NOT B is not attracted to A

Comment: great! haven't thought about doing it that way :) thanks!